# Setting up Python environment for interfacing Intel Galileo

Tags: python, windows, intel-galileo

I am starting off with the Intel Galileo, so far I've been able to use the Arduino IDE and the example programs and work on sensors. But they are all in C. I want to use Python, but I don't know the softwares required for me to install and run a simple Python code on my Intel Galileo.

I'm using it on Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the Intel IoT Devkit image, you'll have everything you need to run python apps.

You can download it at https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/iotdk/board-boot-image.html

Find your board IP address and you'll be able to SSH into it. Using the vi editor, you'll be able to write your python scripts.